# Mysql - Get id from string array column and order

Tags: mysql

this is a bit tricky.
I have a mysql table representing users, each user has a categories column that is delimited with <..> -

```
id       Categories
1        <1><5><7>
2        <2><5><6>
3        <2><4><5><6>
4        <2><5><7><9>
5        <3><2><8>
...
```

Now, I receive an array with a list of categories (i.e - 1, 3, 6), and I need to fetch the rows that contain those categories, and also ORDERED according to their place in the array - 1 is most important, after that 3 and last is 6.
In this example I should receive rows 1, 5, 2, 3.
Any suggestion for a clean and fast query?
Thanks!

Comment: It's ludicrous, but _almost_ meets your requirement. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65d454/7 This table structure is quite unusual, and as you are finding out, will never be easy to work with. It would be much better to normalize out the categories into another table with a sort order.

Comment: Thanks Michael, using regex is a solution I didn't think of, that's great.
What would be in your opinion the best practice to link categories to users where their number can vary?

Comment: A many-to-many joining table called `categories_users` which has 3 columns: `user_id, category_id, sort_order` such that one row represents one category membership for a user.  The `sort_order` column holds the category's position in the list. Querying the order per your requirement still wouldn't be simple, but at least wouldn't require resorting to piles of string operations.

Comment: Well actually the sort changes each time since it depends on a search query. a client search for a string, the system fetch relevant categories accordingly, and then relevant users should appear. I thought also of a many-to-many table, I just wasn't sure if it would be harder to manage/query since there are many users and they change their categories. Maybe the best way would be to use your regex and then sort it on code?

Comment: No matter what, you would need to build the `ORDER BY` dynamically based on the categories you query for. I'd still recommend using a many-to-many table for this even if you sort in code, because then you can use a clause like `WHERE category_id IN (1,3,6)` indexable and with better performance. It is easier to add and delete categories too since you would just be removing a row to remove a user->category relationship

Answer (score 1):

I would personally get all the categories in no particular order with some query like this:

```
select id from foo WHERE `category` LIKE '%<1>%' OR  `category` LIKE '%<3>%' OR  `category` LIKE '%<6>%';
```

and get back the result set and give each row a score and order them.
I believe mysql does it's optimization so it would be hard to order them.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74494f/9

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well that was the easy way, you really think that it's best to do the ordering on the results instead on the query?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner way to do it using `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE `category` REGEXP '<1>|<3>|<6>';
```